# How to call a python script with command line arguments from another python script with command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line

I have two files file1.py and demo.py. What I am trying to do is that I want to call demo.py from file1.py with command line arguments as following:
**python demo.py --config-file output/config.yaml --input datasets/test/28.jpg -c 0.27 --output detectimage --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS output/model_final.pth**

and demo.py must return some values to file1.py. I did not find any way around to do both(calling with command line arguments and get values in return). I tried using os.system(), sys.start() but nothing works.

Comment: Factor out the part that parses command line arguments into a main function, and the part that actually uses parsed arguments into a separate function. When calling from the other script, don't use command line arguments but pass the arguments directly into the other function.

Comment: ideally you do not call demo.py with commandline arguments, but instead import demo.py and call the methods that actually need to be called.